# Vue: Binding radio to boolean

Tags: vuejs2

I'm having trouble binding radiobuttons to boolean values in model.

In this example: https://jsfiddle.net/krillko/npv1snzv/2/

On load, the radio radio button is not checked, and when I try to change them, the 'primary' value in model is becomes empty.

I've tried:

```
:checked="variation.primary == true"
```

but with no effect.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To bind radio buttons to boolean values instead of string values in Vue, use v-bind on the value attribute:

```
<input type="radio" v-model="my-model" v-bind:value="true">
<input type="radio" v-model="my-model" v-bind:value="false">
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to match these values with your backend data.

Checkboxes are not so good for this scenario; the user could leave them both blank, and you don't get your answer. If you are asking a yes/no or true/false question where you want only one answer, then you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: The name attribute, which is needed, but which I left out of my example, shouldn't affect this in any way. I'm not sure why it would be causing a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `checkbox`. Here is an [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npv1snzv/5/).

Your use case is not how radio buttons are supposed to work.

Look at this example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    picked: 'One',
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" id="one" value="One" v-model="picked">
  <label for="one">One</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="picked">
  <label for="two">Two</label>
  <br><br>
  <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've seen the documentation for it, but I'm matching data from backend, and was hoping to do it directly in vue.

Comment: `v-model` is giving `null` because your radio button `value` attribute is `null`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself too, the thing to remember is that the `value` attribute actually shouldn't change for the radio button, what changes (and what you need to bind to) is the `checked` attribute.

And then you need to handle the change event to set the correct item's value in your data.

Based on your jsFiddle, I think this is what you're looking for:

```html
<div id="l-main">
    <div v-for="(variation, key) in variations">

        <label>

          {{ variation.name }}

          <input 
            type="radio"         
            name="Test"
            :value="key"
            :checked="variation.primary"
            @change="onChange"
            />

        </label>
    </div>

    <br>Output:<br>
    <div v-for="(variation, key) in variations">
        {{ variation.name }} {{ variation.primary }}
    </div>

</div>
```

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#l-main',
    data: {
        variations: {
            '41783' : {
                'name': 'test1',
                'primary': false
            },
            '41785' : {
                'name': 'test2',
                'primary': true
            }        
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange($event) {  
            // the primary variation is the one whose key
            // matches the value of the radio button that got checked
            for (const key in this.variations) {
                this.variations[key].primary = key === $event.target.value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```